# Name for a pseudometric: $d(x,y) = \inf_{\sigma} \lVert x- y\circ\sigma\rVert_1$

Tags: reference-request, vectors

I would like to know if the following notion of distance* has been considered in the literature, and if so under which name(s):

For $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, let
$$
d(x,y) =  \inf_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n} \lVert x- y\circ\sigma\rVert_1 = \inf_{\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_n} \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert x_i - y_{\sigma(i)}\rvert
$$
where $\mathcal{S}_n$ is the symmetric group on $\{1,\dots,n\}$, i.e. the group of all permutations. Equivalently, $d(x,y)$ is the $\ell_1$ distance between the vectors $x,y$ *after sorting their coordinates*.

(The asterisk above is because this does not define a distance, but instead a pseudometric: it doesn't satisfy the axiom of identity of indiscernibles.)

Is there a standard name for $d$? "Sorted $\ell_1$ distance" does not seem to bear many results...

PS: I am actually mostly interested as $d$ as a pseudometric on $\Delta(\{1,\dots,n\})$, i.e. over the set of vectors with non-negative entries summing to one. But I figure the general case is as relevant.

Comment: It is a special case of the Earth Mover Distance, which is a special case of the Wasserstein metric. Finding the minimizing $\sigma$ is known as the Bipartite Matching Problem and there are many results in theoretical computer science (and transportation theory) related to this.

Comment: For example (where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is considered): https://web.stanford.edu/~pavone/papers/Treleaven.Pavone.ea.CDC11.pdf

Comment: @adfriedman i came to this from EMD, which is not exactly expressed that way from what i could see in the literature (EMD, and Wasserstein, are metrics: this is not). Essentially, I'd like to know if that quantity (deriving from EMD) had been studied for itself elsewhere, and if so under which name.

Comment: There is no assumption of metric vs pseudo metric in general bipartite matching problems. You have to consider the measure of minimizers (in that paper, for instance, they show that almost all input/output sets have a unique matching).

Comment: I'm merely mentioning that this ("my" quantity)  derives from EMD/Wasserstein, but is not a special case of them.  Since the former is not a metric,  while the latter are.

Comment: @adfriedman because two different vectors,  say (1,0,0) and (0,1,0), can have distance zero.

Comment: Why does that concern you? Is there anything you need to do so that either discernibility is required or that a metric on the quotient classes wouldn’t suffice?

Comment: “L1 bipartite matching”: https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~pettie/matching/Agarwal-Sharathkumar-geometric-transportation.pdf

Comment: @adfriedman I'll have a look at the links, but again: I know how the quantity I'm interested derives from EMD (this is how I got to it), and also my messages above were not about me being focused on the fact that it ("my" quantity) only is a pseudometric; instead, I was pointing out that your initial claim that "it's a special case of EMD" is not true, since *EMD is a metric and this is not*.

Comment: If you let me know what kind of thing you’re applying this to or what aspects interest you then I might be able to make further suggestions. I did a fair bit of research using these kinds of pseudometrics for my masters thesis

Comment: @adfriedman I'd like to know if randomized embeddings of this pseudometric into lower dimensional spaces (endowed with another metric, sepcifically the standard $\ell_1$) has been studied somewhere. If not, if anything of that ilk has been.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an attested name, but I can suggest a reasonable name.

Consider these two metric spaces:

1. Consider first $X=(\mathbb R^n,\ell^1)$, the Euclidean space with the $\ell^1$ norm.
   The permutation group $S_n$ acts on $\mathbb R^n$ by permuting the components.
   Let $Q=X/S_n$ be the quotient of the space $X$ by this action, obtained from $X$ by identifying different points on the same orbit.
   The quotient inherits a metric from $X$ in the standard way.
2. Let $Y=(\mathbb R^n,d)$ be the Euclidean space with your semimetric.
   A semimetric gives rise to an equivalence relation given by
   $$
   x\sim y
   \iff
   d(x,y)=0.
   $$
   Once you take the quotient $P=Y/{\sim}$, you are left with a metric space.
   The semimetric $d$ gives rise to a metric on $P$, and in fact I would even say that the metric on $P$ is $d$.
   The $d$-distance is independent of choices of representatives of an equivalence class, so everything is well defined.

The point is that the spaces $X$ and $Y$ can be naturally identified, and this identification is an isometry.
The quotient by the action of the permutation group is precisely the quotient by the relation $\sim$.

I have not seen this semimetric before, because of this structure, I would call it the **permutation quotient $\ell^1$ metric** (as a metric on the quotient $Q=P$ or a semimetric on $\mathbb R^n$ by metonymy), or the **$\ell^1$ norm modulo permutations**.

Comment: I like the suggestions, but my goal is to find relevant literature for a lit review (and avoid re-proving the same thing as 70 other papers)... +1, though.

Comment: @ClementC. I thought so, but as there were no answers, I thought it might be of some use to record this here. My hope was that this answers might provide keywords to find relevant literature, but I had no luck with my quick look.